# How to estimate similarity between several probability distributions?

Tags: probability, similarities, kullback-leibler

I have several set of probability distributions. I want to reliably estimate consistency across distributions inside each set.

Literature contains methods to compare two distributions: Kullback-Leibler divergence, earth mover's distance, ... But I couldn't find anything for more than two distributions.

I can imagine an indice built on top of one of these methods. For example, I could first merge all probability distributions into a single one. And then use the mean (or median) of the symmetric KL (or any other distance/divergence/...) between the merged distribution and all others distributions in the considered set.
But before starting something out of the blue, I would rather be sure that nothing already exists.

Comment: Jenson=Shannon divergence provide such an estimate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence.